# yii2 fixtures doesn't work properly

Tags: testing, yii2, fixture

I have a problem with fixtures in yii2 , I just created all  required file according to [this document](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/test-fixtures.md) but it's not working.
let me explain , I have a module called Authyii and inside this module I have a model named User .
this is my directory structure :
[image]

my fixture file is like this :

```
namespace app\modules\Authyii\tests\fixtures;


use app\modules\Authyii\models;
use yii\test\ActiveFixture;
use yii\test\Fixture;

class UserFixture extends ActiveFixture
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\modules\Aythyii\models\User';
    public $tableName = 'authyii_user';

}
```

this is my command line :
[image]

but after I type 'yes' and command line says :
[image]

but when I check my database there is not new record inside authyii_user tables .
what I missed ?

Comment: Is namespace 'app\modules\Aythyii\models\User' correct ? change "Aythyii" to "Authyii"

Comment: @RaminMousavi thanks for your attention , I correct the typo but the problem is still exists.

Answer (score 1):

File `User.php` id data dir must have table name `authyii_user.php`. In framework source code in file `ActiveFixture.php` line with code:

```
$dataFile = dirname($class->getFileName()) . '/data/'
    . $this->getTableSchema()->fullName . '.php';
```

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

There is method getFixturesConfig() in \vendor\yiisoft\yii2\console\controllers\FixtureController.php

```
private function getFixturesConfig($fixtures)
{
    $config = [];

    foreach ($fixtures as $fixture) {

        $isNamespaced = (strpos($fixture, '\\') !== false);
        $fullClassName = $isNamespaced ? $fixture . 'Fixture' : $this->namespace . '\\' . $fixture . 'Fixture';

        if (class_exists($fullClassName)) { // <<< I think you lose your UserFixture here
            $config[] = $fullClassName;
        }
    }

    return $config;
}
```

You should check what `$fullClassName` Yii expects it to be (for example logging or echoing it) and tweak your `UserFixture`'s namespace accordingly.